# Node.js wait until request is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm trying to make a simple app that requests some data from an API. I'm building it with express and I have the following code that does the request:

```
module.exports = {
    getPrevMatches: function(){
        request({
            uri: 'http://worldcup.sfg.io/matches',
            json: true
        }, this.process);
    },
    process: function(error, response, body){
        if(response.statusCode === 200){
            return body;
        }
    }
}
```

And the following in my express script:

```
app.get('/previous', function (req, res){
    var prevMatches = worldcup.getPrevMatches();

    console.log(prevMatches);

    res.render('prev.html', {
        prevMatches: prevMatches
    });
});
```

prevMatches is always undefined at this point. I thought that the request package would wait until, well, the request was finished and then proceed with my code. Is this not the case?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you'll get a callback once it's done. Your callback - process - won't be called until the request is complete, but your code does not wait for that to happen.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ah, I see. thanks for the explanation. what do you suggest I could do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a callback based approach (like stated in the comments):

```
function getPrevMatches(cb) {
    request({
        uri: 'http://worldcup.sfg.io/matches',
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if (response.statusCode === 200){
            cb(body);
        }
        // Do error handling here!
    });
}

module.exports = {
    getPrevMatches: getPrevMatches
}
```

As you can see there is no need to export the process function. The calling code now becomes:

```
app.get('/previous', function(req, res){
    worldcup.getPrevMatches(function(prevMatches) {
        console.log(prevMatches);

        res.render('prev.html', {
            prevMatches: prevMatches
        });
    });
});
```

First remark: you still have to handle the errors from the request call (added as a comment).

Second remark: you might want to like at a Promises based approach to avoid callback hell. Request has a very nice promises based wrapper called conveniently [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

Answer (score 1):

It is a good use case for promises.
There are many libs, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise for example.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
module.exports = {
    getPrevMatches: function(){
        return rp({
            uri: 'http://worldcup.sfg.io/matches',
            json: true
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if `this.process` would work in this context

```
app.get('/previous', function (req, res){
    var prevMatches = worldcup.getPrevMatches();
    prevMatches.then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      res.render('prev.html', {
          prevMatches: data
      });
    })
    prevMatches.catch(function (e) {
      res.status(500, {
          error: e
      });
    });
});
```